# Deploying Pre-Configured SQLite DB

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite

We're trying to deploy some very basic user management features along with our software. We'll have a couple of tables (`Users`, `Groups`, `Rights`) with no more than a thousand rows. The database will come pre-configured with certain rights, but groups and users will be up to the end user to create using our GUI.

My question is this:

- How can I set up the "defaults" for this database upon deployment?
- How can I go about securing this database? (It will be an offline DB,
  and thus never 100% secure, but I'd prefer to at least put a password
  on it.)
- Can I set the database files as "Embedded Resources" so that they're 
  hidden from Windows Explorer, and the layman?
- Should I be doing any part of this with the SQLite Visual Studio Designer tools? Or should I keep it all in code?

Answer (score 0):

For your question, I think here is my answer to some points:

- Default: Do you mean default settings, which are stored in tables? You can have a default.sql file and import that during installation.
- Security: Fossil-scm, which from the same author as SQLite, handles this in some way. Fossil generates a project ID, a unique long number, and use this ID as a salt for password SHA-1 generation. ([Fossil-scm password management](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/password.wiki)) However, this is still not enough if you require higher security level.
- Embedded: Personally, I don't think so. Embedded resource is compiled into assembly file and thus it is given a fix offsets in the assembly. I don't think it can re-size.
- Design tool: I think that's OK, either code is OK too.